# How can I implement custom shadow logic in dotnet Maui?

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, maui

I want to code my own shadows similarly to how you're able to override control logic using Maui handlers. I tried looking for a ShadowHandler class or IShadowHandler but couldn't find anything. Is there something available to do in Maui?

Comment: Any particular reason to not use the Shadow property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/shadow?view=net-maui-7.0) ? Otherwise you will probably have to create a custom renderer (you can look at exemple in Xamarin : https://medium.com/xamarinlife/customising-frame-shadow-in-xamarin-forms-everything-you-need-to-know-6572a45fd519 and see if the same logic can be ported : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: Shadows don't work in Android 13 with a particular build version and I can't afford to wait anymore for Maui devs to fix it since its been in the backlog for almost a year -> https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10401. I'll give what you sent a shot though, thank you :)

Comment: Is this really MAUI issue? Not Android?

Comment: Considering other android apps still have shadows, and the Maui GraphicsView shadows work on this version then yes, I'd say this is a MAUI issue. The issue is related to the Shadow class.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the issue you provided carefully.

First of all, there are two links about [BlurMaskFilter not blurring bitmaps correctly in Android 13](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238769745) and [Android 13: Paint.setShadowLayer() or BlurMaskFilter behaves differently than in previous Android versions](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244121207) in the issue. The two are both the native issues for the shadow in the android 13.

It seems the Shadow class in the maui call the **native android BlurMaskFilter api** to create shadow in the android. So the problem appeared.

And then the comment said:

> Switch your Android SDK Manager to the Google feed and update your Android 13 - API33 emulator build to v7.
> That version includes the Android OS fix.

I tested the emulator with both this in the visual studio and the newest android 13 sdk version in android studio. The problem disappeared.

So if you want to resolve this in the old android 13 version, you can try to use the custom render for the control you want to add a shadow and [use the other native codes for the android](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=android+add+shadow+to+view&source=hp&ei=-Ls8ZJiDLNDE4-EPhbCqoAU&iflsig=AOEireoAAAAAZDzKCAAV4u4HFnhQltyu1DfjNdg-YwrN&oq=android+add+shadow&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIICAAQigUQhgM6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoLCC4QigUQsQMQgwE6CwguEIAEEMcBENEDOgsIABCKBRCxAxCDAToICC4QgAQQsQM6CwguENQCELEDEIAEOhEILhCDARDHARCxAxDRAxCABDoICAAQgAQQsQM6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOgUILhCABDoRCC4QgwEQrwEQxwEQsQMQgAQ6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBEK8BOgoIABCABBCxAxAKOgcIABCABBAKUABYhyhglTZoAHAAeACAAXKIAa0NkgEEMTQuNJgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz).